# How to calculate balance in payment and invoice page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this page showing invoice and payments, I want to calculate balance at end each row of the table.
I have my records sorted on `DESC` order that's why I am unable to get it right.

The result is in below picture, It is sorted by created at, I want that the type `Payment` is deducted from the balance and the last row balance column show $-30, in the second column it show $70.
The invoice amount should be added to the balance.

**Student Modal**

```
    public function billings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Billing::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

**Billing Modal**

```
    public function billingRecords()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BillingRecord::class, 'billing_id');
    }
```

DataTable / HTML

```
<table class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-Room">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Type</th>
       <th>Amount</th>
       <th>Balance</th>
       <th>&nbsp;</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>             
   <tbody>
     @php
       $balance = 0;
     @endphp

     @foreach($student->billings as $key => $billing)
        @php
          $total = 0;
          $tooltip = "";
        @endphp

        <tr data-entry-id="{{ $billing->id }}">
           <td>
             <p class="m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('M d, Y') ?? '' }}</p>
             <p class="small m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('h:i A') ?? '' }}</p>
           </td>

           <td>{{ $billing->type ?? '' }}</td>

           <td>
             @foreach ($billing->billingRecords as $record)
                @php
                  $total += $record->amount;
                @endphp
             @endforeach

             @if($billing->type == "Payment")
                 $-{{ $total }}
             @elseif($billing->type == "Invoice")
                 ${{ $total }}
             @endif
           </td>

           <td>
             $ {{ $balance += $total }}
           </td>
                 
         </tr>
       @endforeach
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

**Current Result**
[image]

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? This looks like stuff that should not be calculated within a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about directly adjusting the `$total`?

```
<tr data-entry-id="{{ $billing->id }}">
    <td>
        <p class="m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('M d, Y') ?? '' }}</p>
        <p class="small m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('h:i A') ?? '' }}</p>
    </td>

    <td>{{ $billing->type ?? '' }}</td>
     
    <td>
        @foreach ($billing->billingRecords as $record)
            @php
                $total += $record->amount;
            @endphp
        @endforeach
        @php
            if ($billing->type == "Payment") {
                $total *= -1;
            }
        @endphp

        ${{ $total }}
    </td>

     <td>
         $ {{ $balance += $total }}
     </td>
                 
</tr>
```

---

```
public function billings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Billing::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
    }
```

```
@php
    $balance = 0;
    $billings = $student->billings->map(function($billing) use(&$balance) {
        $billing->total = $billing->billingRecords->sum('amount');
        if ($billing->type == "Payment") {
            $billing->total *= -1;
        }
        $billing->balance = ($balance += $billing->total);
        return $billing;
    })->reverse();
@endphp
@foreach($billings as $key => $billing)
    @php
        $tooltip = "";
    @endphp

    <tr data-entry-id="{{ $billing->id }}">
        <td>
            <p class="m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('M d, Y') ?? '' }}</p>
            <p class="small m-0">{{ $billing->created_at->format('h:i A') ?? '' }}</p>
        </td>

        <td>{{ $billing->type ?? '' }}</td>

        <td>${{ $billing->total }}</td>

        <td>$ {{ $billing->balance }}</td>
                
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

You can also clean this a bit up:

1. Run `php artisan make:collection \\App\\Collections\\BillingCollection`
2. Add

```php
<?php

namespace App\Collections;

use DatePeriod;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
 
class ExampleCollection extends Collection
{
    public function processed()
    {
        $balance = 0;
        return $this->map(function($billing) use(&$balance) {
            $billing->total = $billing->billingRecords->sum('amount');
            if ($billing->type == "Payment") {
                $billing->total *= -1;
            }
            $billing->balance = ($balance += $billing->total);
            return $billing;
        })->reverse();
    }
}
```

Inside your `Billing` model add this:

```
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {   
        return new BillingCollection($models);
    }
```

Comment: No, it just show the balance same as amount.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with the answer?

Comment: is it for amount column or balance column?

Comment: I have problem with balance column

Comment: I know. Because you're calculating with a positive `$total`.

Comment: If you look at balance column. First I paid $30, the bottom column should show $-30, after that invoice is created of $100, the top balance column should show $70.

Comment: I bet, that is, what's happening if you apply my changes. What about giving them a try?

Comment: Lol, why I am not getting it :) , Kindly post for both amount column and balance column so I can place this code in correct column

Comment: I added the whole row for better understanding

Comment: This is show $100 in first row and $70 in second row which is not correct, I want that balance to be calculated from bottom to top, like from bottom to top the balance should be $-30 and then $70

Comment: You have to loop over it the other way round first and make an array that you can access in the loop you already have.

Comment: In student model I am getting billings() in DESC order that is why the calculation is making the problem

Comment: Okay, I added an alternative solution below the horizontal line.

Comment: Giving me error ```Trying to get property 'num' of non-object ```

Comment: Oh, it has to be `->map()` instead of `->reduce()`. I update my answer.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't do that in my test setup. Can you check the formulas inside the `map()`?

Comment: I am not getting where that ```num``` is coming from

Comment: Interesting question. I was so sure, it was an attribute of the model. But you're right, it's not.

Comment: Anyway. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you helped a lot :) I appreciate you for your kind response to my question

Comment: No problem. I'm glad, I could help. It was indeed a tough one ^^