# How to calculate balance when the records I want to show in desc order?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to to show the recently created amount at the top but also I want to show the balance column, the balance column will add or subtract the amount from the record

**Controller**

```
$ledgerTransactions = LedgerRecord::where('ledger_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
```

**Blade**

```
@php
  $balance = 0;
  $ledgerTransactions = $ledgerTransactions->map(function($transaction) use(&$balance) {
    $transaction->total = $transaction->sum('amount');
    if ($transaction->type == "Payment") {
      $transaction->total *= -1;
    }
    $transaction->balance = ($balance += $transaction->total);
    return $transaction;
  })->reverse();
@endphp

@foreach($ledgerTransactions as $transaction)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="mb-0">{{ $transaction->created_at->format('M d, Y') }}</p>
        </td>
        <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $transaction->description ?? '' }}</td>
        <td>
            ${{ $transaction->amount }}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${{ $transaction->balance }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The problem with this is it starts adding from top, which I don't want. I want it starts adding from bottom

Expected results are marked in red color in below image

[image]

Comment: Does that answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722591/how-to-calculate-balance-in-payment-and-invoice-page-in-laravel/67722805#67722805

Comment: I have tried that but it is giving be double of the amount,

Comment: @shaedrich I have updated my code, which I have tried so far

Comment: Could you please also add a short example table of the expected vs the actual result?

Comment: I have added expected result image

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize, the linked question is your's :D

Comment: But it looks simplier than the other example. Would you mind showing me the database table structure to see what the model looks like?

Comment: @shaedrich hahaha yes that was mine :)

Comment: Are you sure, it still starts from top since you're using `reverse()`?

Comment: It is fine now, like the above picture, also your solution works will but I want to deduct the amount which has type "Payment"

Comment: Isn't it done by the `if`?

Comment: I am currently using your solution which don't have if, nor do I have in my question

Comment: You do, but I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something as easy as this:

```
@php
  $balance = 0;
  $ledgerTransactions = $ledgerTransactions->map(function($transaction) use(&$balance) {
    $transaction->total = $transaction->amount;
    if ($transaction->type == "Payment") {
      $transaction->total *= -1;
    }
    $transaction->balance = ($balance += $transaction->total);
    return $transaction;
  })->reverse();
@endphp

@foreach($ledgerTransactions as $transaction)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="mb-0">{{ $transaction->created_at->format('M d, Y') }}</p>
        </td>
        <td class="font-weight-bold">{{ $transaction->type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $transaction->description ?? '' }}</td>
        <td>
            ${{ $transaction->amount }}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${{ $transaction->balance }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have to check for transaction type, if it is "Payment" it will be deducted from balance

Comment: But that's what you're doing: 0 + 100 = 100, 100 + 30 = 130, 130 - 50 = 80

Comment: I have a mistake in line 4, ```$transaction->sum('amount');```

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.